# Meteor.js-like templates for PHP

Tags: php, templates

I have been using Meteor.js for all my projects for the last 2 years, but I have accepted a project that uses PHP, and it still does not have a proper templating engine, its using only simple includes and php echos everywhere.

I really like mustache-like syntax, but, what really sets Meteor.js style templates apart is the ability to both run helper functions like #each, #if/else, per template helpers and that you can define more than one template per file.

I want to find a templating engine similar to this, to avoid creating my own.

Often, I set many small templates on the same page as the "bigger" one like so :

```
<template name="post">
{{ user.name }} said :
{{> postTextTemplate }}
</template>
<template name="postTextTemplate">
{{ postText }}
<hr>
At {{ postDate }} - {{ postLikes }} likes.
</template>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up creating my own meta-language using underscore.js templates and custom regex rules for <@ code @> and <@= code @>

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Blade](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#blade-templating) which seems to be exactly what you want, however you can't use Blade without Laravel behind it. There are a few [standalone libraries](https://github.com/PhiloNL/Laravel-Blade) you can use, however.

Rather than the `#` syntax you're used to Blade uses `@` so you can do some cool things in your views such as:

```
@if($shouldLoop)
    @for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
        <p>{{ $i }}</p>
    @endfor
@else
    <p>I shouldn't loop</p>
@endif
```

Otherwise, there's various libraries such as [bobthecow's mustashe.php](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki) which provides an implementation of mustashe in PHP.

Comment: It doesnt seem to be possible to have templates all in one file like Meteor.js allows, this is a massive productivity and clarity boost, some small pages have 5-6 templates, and having one on each file is madness.